# Replacement of M_ASN1_I2D * in OpenSSL 3.0

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm migrating openSSL from 1.0.2z to openSSL 3.0.
I'm not able to find the replacement of M_ASN1_I2D* functions.
M_ASN1_I2D_len, M_ASN1_I2D_put, M_ASN1_I2D_seq_total, ASN1_I2D_vars, M_ASN1_I2D_finish

The were earlier declared in file asn1_mac.h (which is deprecated in OpenSSL 3.0), can someone please help me identify the document or their replacement in OpenSSL 3.0

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research I'm able to find the alternate
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/20574

Comment: Link-only answers are subject to link rot.  Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers